# Largest Perimeter Triangle Leetcode Problem Python

Tags: python, greedy

I have given the mentioned problem quite a thought but was not able to come up with a working solution on my own. So I found the following solution, but I want to understand why does it work. Here it is:

```
class Solution:
    def largestPerimeter(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        # triange in-equality a+b > c
        # sum of 2 smallest > largest
        nums.sort(reverse=True)
        a,b,c = inf,inf,inf
        for n in nums:
            a, b, c = n, a, b
            if a + b > c:
                return a+b+c       
        return 0
```

Now I will write how I understand this code works and what I do not understand.
So. The list is sorted in a descending way with nums.sort(reverse=True). Then a, b, c are given values of infinity each. Then on the first iteration of the for cycle a, b, c are set equal to: a - the highest value from nums; b, c - infinity. Then the program checks if the highest value from nums + infinity is higher than infinity. But isn`t this condition true for any value of a? And even if I understood the condition, why is the output equal to a+b+c = highest value from nums + infinity + infinity? How can this be a valid perimeter for a triangle?

Comment: What exactly is "the mentioned problem" about? What is `nums`?

Comment: On each iteration, `a`, `b` and `c` will shift over the list of `nums`, eventually they will all get assign integer numbers instead of inf (starting from the 3rd iteration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But isn't this condition true for any value of a?

No, that condition is false for any value of `a`.

In the first iteration, `a + b > c` will resolve to `n0 + inf > inf`. Now, `n0 + inf` returns `inf` for any integer `n0`, so `inf > inf` is false.

Also, in the second iteration, you will have `n1 + n0 > inf`, which is also always false.

Only in the third iteration, all the `inf`s will be gone and you will start having `n2 + n1 > n0`, then actual comparisons will happen.

Maybe it would be more clear if the implementation was something like this equivalent code:

```
nums.sort(reverse=True)
# extract the first 2 elements in a and b, 
# and reassign all the remaining back to nums
b, a, *nums = nums  
for n in nums:
    a, b, c = n, a, b
    if a + b > c:
        return a+b+c
```

Please note that, by doing this, you would need to treat the special cases where `len(nums) < 3`.